# symfony2 js twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

i wanna pass a json result parameter to a twig format in file "A.js.twig" as follow:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "managemore",
          success: function(msg){

            var ret = $.parseJSON(msg)
            var str = '';
             for (var i=0; i<ret.deliverLength; i++)
             {
                str = str + "<a href=\" {{ path('changeJob', {'jid':ret.deliver[i]['jid']}) }} \", target=\"_self\" ><li>hello</li></a>";
             }

           },
           error: function(XmlHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                 alert("fail");
            }
});
```

it went wrong...so how can i pass the ret.deliver[i]["jid"] in the twig format in the right way?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: try https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

Comment: i have used the FOSJsRoutingBundle..but i dont know how to pass the parameter.i tried,but fail.

Comment: it cant understand what's the value of js parameter"ret.deliver[i]['jid'] " in twig in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check documentation for FOSJsRoutingBundle : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

To generate route using this bundle use one of example statements:

```
Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10 });
// will result in /foo/10/bar

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10, foo: "bar" });
// will result in /foo/10/bar?foo=bar

$.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10, foo: "bar" }));
// will call /foo/10/bar?foo=bar

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose_with_defaults');
// will result in /blog/1

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose_with_defaults', { id: 2 });
// will result in /blog/2

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose_with_defaults', { foo: "bar" });
// will result in /blog/1?foo=bar

Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose_with_defaults', { id: 2, foo: "bar" });
// will result in /blog/2?foo=bar
```

For your problem it will looks smt like this:

```
str = str + Routing.generate('changeJob', { jid: ret.deliver[i]['jid']}) + <li>hello</li>   </a>";
```